# EF Core dbcontext scaffolder does not fire OperationReportHandler events

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I wrote .NET Core `dbcontext scaffolder` method to generate Entity classes and DbContext. Everything works, but the errorList, warningList, infoList, verboseList are always empty ... how to fix `OperationReportHandler` to work?

```
        var errorList = new List<string>();
        var warningList = new List<string>();
        var infoList = new List<string>();
        var verboseList = new List<string>();

        var reporter = new OperationReporter(
                        new OperationReportHandler(
                            m => errorList.Add((m)),
                            m => warningList.Add((m)),
                            m => infoList.Add((m)),
                            m => verboseList.Add((m))));

        var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddScaffolding(reporter)
            .AddSingleton<IOperationReporter, OperationReporter>()
            .AddSingleton<IOperationReportHandler, OperationReportHandler>();

        IDesignTimeServices provider = new Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.SqlServerDesignTimeServices();
        provider.ConfigureDesignTimeServices(serviceCollection);

        var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

        var generator = serviceProvider.GetService<IModelScaffolder>();

        var filePaths = generator.Generate(
                                    Config.ConnectionString,
                                    Config.Tables,
                                    Config.Schemas,
                                    Config.ProjectPath,
                                    Config.OutputPath,
                                    Config.RootNamespace,
                                    Config.ContextName,
                                    false, //useDataAnnotations
                                    Config.OverwriteFiles,
                                    Config.UseDatabaseNames);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line...

```
.AddSingleton<IOperationReporter, OperationReporter>()
```

...to this.

```
.AddSingleton<IOperationReporter>(reporter)
```

P.S. This is simpler in EF Core 2.1:

```
var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection()
    .AddEntityFrameworkDesignTimeServices(reporter);
```